# Is there any issue on editing PodFile in Xcode iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podfile

I have a pod file of SideMenuController in Swift. I need to edit the code in pod file within Xcode.

Is there any problem on editing pod files in iOS? 
I were added the pod files using terminal action. If i edit those files, is it affect my project?

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: first of all share your podfile so that we can see, Secondly mention what do you want to change in it ?

Comment: I want to make a change in pod file. Is it make any issue in my app? @EricAya  .

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Also, your changes won't be propagated to other colleges you work with. It will work only for you. Better thing to do is to fork it and use your own.

Comment: What change exactly ? do you want to remove or add some libraries ?